# ¿Como enviar parametros desde un archivo de php a otro y enviar por correo?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Tengo un archivo php que realiza una consulta a una base de datos mysql y en caso de excepción inserta un registro en una tabla que lo llamo notificaciónes parte de consulta e insert funciona muy bien.

Bueno lo quisiera hacer es que cuando lanze una excepcion se pueda enviar estas tres variables ($hoy, $ip, $mensaje)  del insert a otro archivo php para que este lo envie por correo y cree una función en un archivo que deberia recibir los parametros del insert y no logro hacerlo funcionar.

bueno no tengo el suficiente conocimiento con este lenguaje php pero lo estoy intentando de esta manera aqui dejo mi codigo si se puede una ayudita por favor

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    include 'conexionMySQL.php';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');


    $return_arr = array();

    $conexion = new  conexionMySQL();
    $conn = $conexion->conectar();

    $colab = $_POST["c"];
    $altura = "";

    $ge = "SELECT * FROM organigrama_alturas WHERE alturaadicionalfunc = '$colab'";
    $ger = $conn->query($ge);
    while ($rowger = mysqli_fetch_array($ger)) {
        $altura = $rowger["alturaadicionalaltura"];
        $row_array['success'] = "true";


        $row_array['altura'] = $altura;
        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    }


    if ($altura != "") {


    } else {
        $row_array['success'] = "false";
        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);


        $hoy = date("y-m-d H:i:s");
        $ip = empty($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) ? "Desconocida" : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $mensaje = 'Error al recuperar en la tabla organigrama_alturas  en (organigrama/inc/archivo1.php)';


    //////insert
        include_once 'conexionMySQL.php';
        $conexion = new  conexionMySQL();
        $conn = $conexion->conectar();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO NOTIFICACIONES (FECHA, IP, MENSAJE)
    VALUES ('$hoy',' $ip','$mensaje')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Nueva alerta creada";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        enviarmensaje($hoy, $ip, $mensaje);

    }


    echo json_encode($return_arr);
    ?>
```

esta es mi clase de conexión

```
    <?php

    class conexionMySQL
    {
        public function conectar ()
        {
            $mysqli = new mysqli( "127.0.0.1:3307" , "root" , "1234" , "basedatos" );

            if ($mysqli -> connect_error) {
                error_log ( "MySql error" );
            } else {
                if (!$mysqli -> set_charset ( "utf8" )) {
                    error_log ( "Error loading character set utf8: %s\n" , $mysqli -> error );
                    exit();
                } else {
                }

                return $mysqli;
            }
        }
    }

    $class = new conexionMySQL();
    $class -> conectar ();
    ?>
```

y esta es la función a la cual le quiero pasar los datos del insert este archivo funciona para enviar correos pero al recibir un valor desde otro archivo no abre

```
    <?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    public
    function enviarmensaje ( $hoy , $ip , $mensaje )
    {

        require 'mailer/src/Exception.php';
        require 'mailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'mailer/src/SMTP.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer( true );

        try {
            $mail -> SMTPDebug = 0;
            $mail -> isSMTP ();
            $mail -> Host = 'mail.mimail.com.py';
            $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail -> Username = 'micorreo@micorreo.com';
            $mail -> Password = '1234';
            $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail -> Port = 587;
            $mail -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';


            //Recipients
            $mail -> setFrom ( 'micorreo@micorreo.com' , 'Organizacion' );
            $mail -> addAddress ( 'correodestino@gmail.com' );   // Add a recipient
            $mail -> addReplyTo ( 'micorreo@micorreo.com' , 'Organizacion' );


            // Content
            $mail -> isHTML ( true ); // Set email format to HTML
            $mail -> Subject = '[Error en el archivo a_s_1.php]';


            $cuerpo_maill = '<tbody>
      <tr>
      <th  style="padding:12px;border:1px solid #e5e5e5">Fecha -> ' . $hoy . ': </th>
     
      <tr>
      <th  style="padding:12px;border:1px solid #e5e5e5"> IP ->' . $ip . '<th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th  style="padding:12px;border:1px solid #e5e5e5"> MENSAJE ->' . $mensaje . '(organigrama/inc/colaboradores.php)<th>

      </tr>
      
      </tbody>';

            $mail -> Body = ( '<div id="" dir="ltr" style="background-color:#f7f7f7;margin:0;padding:70px 0;width:100%">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
      <div id="">

      </div>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="" style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #dedede;border-radius:3px">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="" style="background-color:#0f0f0f;color:#ffffff;border-bottom:0;font-weight:bold;line-height:100%;vertical-align:middle;font-family:&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;border-radius:3px 3px 0 0">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td id="" style="padding:15px 48px;display:block">
      <h1 style="font-family:&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:30px;font-weight:300;line-height:150%;margin:0;text-align:left;color:#ffffff">Error de datos</h1>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td valign="top" id="" style="background-color:#ffffff">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="padding:48px 48px 32px">
      <div id="" style="color:#636363;font-family:&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:150%;text-align:left">

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="color:#636363;border:1px #e5e5e5;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;margin-bottom:40px">
      ' . $cuerpo_maill . '
      </table>

      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
      </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>

      </div>' );

            $mail -> AltBody = 'Tu navegador o cliente de correo no soporta este tipo de correos :/ ';

            $mail -> send ();
            echo 'Message has been sent';
            echo " <script>alert('Exito! El mensaje fue enviado. ');</script> ";

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
            exit();
            echo " <script>alert('Algo fue mal! Vuelva a intentarlo en un momento. ');</script> ";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Y la función de enviarmensaje está en un script diferente al de las inserciones? Si es así, deberías hacer el include también, no?

Comment: la función de enviar mensaje si es otro script a las de insercion ya lo intente con include no pasa nada

Comment: ordene el codigo del envio de mail ademas le agregue Include al archivo del consulta y funcionó gracias @Alfabravo